# implementing setInterval/clearInterval in nim

Tags: nim-lang

I have the following code which run the passed proc in an interval, and return a clearInterval proc to stop the run, as follow:

```
proc runInterval(cb: proc, interval: int): Future[proc()] {.async.} =
  var stop_run = false
  while not(stop_run):
    await sleepAsync(intv)
    cb()
  
  proc clearInterval() =
    stop_run = true
  
  return clearInterval

proc in_interval() =
  echo "hahah"

let clearInterval = runInterval(in_interval, 1000) # run the in_interval proc every 1 second
clearInterval() # stop in_interval (can't compile)
runForever()
```

I suspect type annotation of runInterval is not correct as

: Future[proc()] {.async.}
, but I dont know how can I define a proc whose returnning type is proc as well as {.async.} ?

Comment: Instead of doing this why not just follow other similar APIs and have the `cb` return a boolean when it wants to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dom96 suggested you should make the closure return bool like so:

```py
import asyncdispatch
import random

proc runInterval(cb: proc, interval: int) {.async.} =
  var stop_run = false
  while not stop_run:
    await sleepAsync(interval)
    if not cb():
      break 

proc in_interval(): bool =
  if rand(1..6) > 2:
    echo "lucky"
    true
  else:
    echo "unlucky"
    false


randomize()

discard runInterval(in_interval, 500)

runForever()
```

Comment: I still think this is not a perfect way to do it, what I want is sth out side of in_interval proc to trigger the stop. I also tried using a global variable such as running flag, and check the flag inside in_interval, unfortunatelly it doesn't work either.

Comment: Th problem with your requirements is that it is actually impossible to do. The while loop has to finish first to return the interrupt. The classic control flow of program still applies.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to implement this pattern by wrapping the while loop in its own async proc and removing the async from the `runInterval` proc to directly return `clearInterval`:

```py
import asyncdispatch

proc runInterval(cb: proc, interval: int): proc() =
  var stop_run = false

  proc clearInterval() =
    stop_run = true

  proc runIntervalLoop() {.async.} =
    while not(stop_run):
      await sleepAsync(interval)
      cb()

  asyncCheck runIntervalLoop()
  
  return clearInterval

proc in_interval() =
  echo "hahah"

proc process {.async.} =
  let clearInterval = runInterval(in_interval, 1000) # run the in_interval proc every 1 second
  await sleepAsync(3000)
  echo "Finished sleeping"
  clearInterval()
  echo "Cleared interval"

waitFor process()
```